# Eclipse Java EE to install C++ module

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse IDE for Java EE packages installed. How can I add the C/C++ IDE to the current Eclipse install? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use **Help > Install** New software to open the Install dialog. There, you'll need to select the right update site from the drop-down list at the top. Depending on which version of Eclipse you have, it will most likely be **Indigo** or **Helios**.

After selecting the update site, the list below will populate with available features to install (be patient, it might take a minute). Look for the "**Programming Languages**" group in that list, expand it, and check the box next to "**C/C++ Development Tools**." If desired, you can also select the "incubation" features for C/C++ or CDT.

Click the `Next` button and follow the prompts to download and install CDT.

Comment: I also installed "C/C++ Development Tools SDK" described as "Eclipse C/C++ development tools. Software development kit including source code and developer documentation."

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3RC2) on Ubuntu. Here are the steps I installed C++ plugins:

```
Help > Eclipse Marketplaces..
In Find input box, enter C++
Scroll down to locate Eclipse C/C++ IDE CDT 9.2 (Neon.2)
Click Install
```

Note: you may see different C/C++ IDE CDT version if you use a different version of Eclipse Java EE IDE

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the steps above to follow, I want to share a side effect of installing C/C++ modules in Java EE Eclipse: your custom hotkeys may not work.

The fix is:

1. Try to "Restore command" in "Preferences" - "Keys".
2. If it doesn't help, you can try to close Java perspective and reopen it. That did the trick for me.

I noticed that when the installation finishes and we restart, we see a C++ welcome screen. I guess that after a installation of CDT, this perspective and its hotkeys takes precedence over Java perspective, thus, reopen Java perspective make Java hotkeys take precedence over C++. But it's more like a bug.